# Invalid answer flag declined even though it can't be improved

Tags: discussion

I've flagged [this](https://superuser.com/a/114470/33758) with

> OP asked about foobar2000, but this answer is about iTunes (see https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=view+menu+-%3E+go+to+current+song&gws_rd=cr)

However, my flag was declined by a moderator who left this comment:

> declined - then it would need a downvote for being on the wrong side of the pair

The matter is that that user has deleted his account, and his answer can't be improved in any fashion without becoming a duplicate of the other answers. It's just adding clutter to the page. Wouldn't it be simpler to just delete it than to keep it online for people just to test it in vain?

The upvotes it received were likely done by people who thought that it was a valid answer without testing it. This screenshot and [the Google link I left](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=view%20menu%20-%3E%20go%20to%20current%20song&gws_rd=cr) prove that it's "on the wrong side of the pair":

[image: foobar2000 screenshot]

Comment: When you flagged it, you flagged it as... what?  Sometimes that's a problem.  I've almost given up on the pre-defined flags because too many flags are valueless when the community goes around asserting actions that show "this question isn't valueless", "this really is an answer", and other nonsense.   I'm almost to a point of giving up entirely on reviewing things because some misguided zealot will choose to prove me wrong.

Comment: @killermist I didn't use a pre-defined tag. You can see the custom text I added to it in my post ("OP asked about foobar2000, but...").

Comment: Thank you.  Sorry.  I misread.  I'm very tempted to only ever use special moderator flags because the community... tends to naysayer-ism.  "Oh, you think this post is unsalvageable.  I'll show you."  "What?  This isn't an answer?  I'll show you."  But, I guess moderators can have an agenda too.  Don't get me wrong.  I love naysayers.  I am one.  But rewarding it makes it worse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the attached account still exists or not doesn't matter.

At the time of the flag the answer did not have any downvotes.

Moderators don't delete in cases of a wrong answer, but of a non-answer. Or of a late duplicate answer.

Since the answer was neither, it's something that would be left to the community to handle.

Comment: Thank you. At least this makes the process more transparent.